# Convert Data.RVar.RVar [Char] to [Char]

Tags: haskell

> cabal install random-extras

```
Prelude Data.Random.Extras> import Data.Random.Extras
Prelude Data.Random.Extras> let s = shuffle "somestring"
Prelude Data.Random.Extras> s

<interactive>:1:1:
    No instance for (Show (Data.RVar.RVar [Char]))
      arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Show (Data.RVar.RVar [Char]))
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

How can I convert Data.RVar.RVar [Char] to [Char] ?

**Updated:**

I can not import Data.Random.Source.DevRandom:

```
Prelude> import Data.Random hiding (shuffle)
Prelude Data.Random> import Data.Random.Source.DevRandom

<no location info>:
    Could not find module `Data.Random.Source.DevRandom':
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

But:

```
[59]: cabal install random-fu
Resolving dependencies...
No packages to be installed. All the requested packages are already installed.
If you want to reinstall anyway then use the --reinstall flag.
[60]: cabal install random-source
Resolving dependencies...
No packages to be installed. All the requested packages are already installed.
If you want to reinstall anyway then use the --reinstall flag.
```

**Updated 2:**

```
*Main System.Random> import Data.Random hiding (shuffle)
*Main System.Random Data.Random> import Data.Random.Source.Std
*Main System.Random Data.Random Data.Random.Source.Std> import Data.Random.Extras
*Main System.Random Data.Random Data.Random.Source.Std Data.Random.Extras> let reversed = runRVar (shuffle "somestring") StdRandom

<interactive>:1:16:
    Ambiguous type variable `m0' in the constraints:
      (MonadRandom m0) arising from a use of `runRVar'
                       at <interactive>:1:16-22
      (Monad m0) arising from a use of `runRVar' at <interactive>:1:16-22
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the expression: runRVar (shuffle "somestring") StdRandom
    In an equation for `reversed':
        reversed = runRVar (shuffle "somestring") StdRandom
```

Comment: `Data.Random.Source.DevRandom` is also included in the `random-extra` package (`[ 9 of 11] Compiling Data.Random.Source.DevRandom ( src/Data/Random/Source/DevRandom.hs, dist/build/Data/Random/Source/DevRandom.o )`).

Comment: maybe random-extras ? i habe it installed too.

Comment: here is log of reinstall http://pastebin.com/pkxzZC9r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this: **EDIT**: Using *StdRandom*

```
import Data.Random hiding (shuffle)
import Data.Random.Source.Std
import Data.Random.Extras

reversed = runRVar (shuffle "somestring") StdRandom

test = do
  x <- reversed
  putStrLn x
```

Comment: I have updated my question: I can not import Data.Random.Source.DevRandom

Comment: Seems like `DevRandom` is not available on Windows. A different random source from the library should do, though.

Comment: Sorry, but no - see Updated 2 in my question :(

Comment: @demas Yes it does, you're just not using it right. The program as a whole works. ghci doesn't accept it this way because of its stronger monomorphism restriction: `reversed` is a monadic value, but it doesn't know which monad to use. But in ghci, you can just extract the value right away from the `IO` monad: `reversed <- runRVar (shuffle "somestring") StdRandom`.