# How to print the results of sampling an RVar

Tags: haskell

I have a program that works. However, I wasn't exactly sure why it was compiling.

Here's my main function

```
module Main where

import System.Environment
import Cover5

main :: IO ()
main = do
         args <- getArgs
         let numGames = if null args then 13 else read $ head args
         putStrLn $ "Making picks for " ++ show numGames ++ " games."
         print $ run numGames
```

where the function `run` has the signature `run :: Int -> RVar [(Int, Char)]`.

What is confusing is that there is no instance of `Show` for `RVar [(Int,Char)]` so I figure it shouldn't compile, but it does (see [Travis-CI build](https://travis-ci.org/michaelgwelch/cover5/builds/192025653) and the related source for that [commit of Main.hs](https://github.com/michaelgwelch/cover5/blob/3ef47f24e436619916a8cc3d4ba3f4726bf48e1c/src/Main.hs)). I can force a warning with this command:

```
cabal build --ghc-options="-fforce-recomp -fno-code"
Preprocessing executable 'cover5' for cover5-0.1.0.1...
[1 of 2] Compiling Cover5           ( src/Cover5.hs, nothing )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( src/Main.hs, nothing )

src/Main.hs:13:10: error:
    • No instance for (Show (RVar [(Int, Char)]))
        arising from a use of ‘print’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ run numGames
      In the expression:
        do { args <- getArgs;
             let numGames = ...;
             putStrLn $ "Making picks for " ++ show numGames ++ " games.";
             print $ run numGames }
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main
            = do { args <- getArgs;
                   let numGames = ...;
                   putStrLn $ "Making picks for " ++ show numGames ++ " games.";
                   .... }
```

I'd like to "fix" this and have followed guidance from the question [Convert Data.RVar.RVar [Char] to [Char]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120612/convert-data-rvar-rvar-char-to-char#13121497)

So I add the appropriate imports for StdRandom and runRVar and write the following lines

```
results <- runRVar (run numGames) StdRandom
putStrLn $ show results
```

But I'm tripping over myself trying to find instances of MonadRandom IO for my usage:

```
src/Main.hs:13:21: error:
    • No instance for (MonadRandom IO) arising from a use of ‘runRVar’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        results <- runRVar (run numGames) StdRandom
      In the expression:
        do { args <- getArgs;
             let numGames = ...;
             putStrLn $ "Making picks for " ++ show numGames ++ " games.";
             results <- runRVar (run numGames) StdRandom;
             .... }
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main
            = do { args <- getArgs;
                   let numGames = ...;
                   putStrLn $ "Making picks for " ++ show numGames ++ " games.";
                   .... }
```

So two questions:

1. Why does the original version compile and work?
2. What might you suggest I do to remove the warning and write this "correctly"?

Comment: I guess an easier approach for me (to fix this) is to convert the (Int,Char) pairs into Strings within the RVar monad. Then I'd align more closely with the problem in the linked question.

Comment: That's not a warning, it's an error. The original version does _not_ compile. Perhaps you've run an old executable with a trivial test that was still lying around?

Comment: OTOH, the `runRVar` version _should_ compile, because there _is_ a `MonadRandom IO` instance. Unless something is very broken with your library environment... or perhaps you've just imported only “internal” modules that don't actually export that instance? What happens if you explicitly import `Data.Random`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout did you try to compile? I'm using ghc 8.0.1 and it does appear to compile and I've included links to travis ci where it does appear to build numerous times using 7.8. I guess I could have a broken env, but then I'd expect Travis to complain as well.

Comment: I'll try the explicit import of Data.Random. (I'm very confused by the packaging of Data.RVar, Data.Random and the like).

Comment: Aha, `Cover5` imports `Data.Random.Show.Unsafe`. Why do people keep doing explicitly **unsafe** things and then come here complaining that strange stuff happens?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133205/discussion-between-michael-welch-and-leftaroundabout).

Comment: `Data.Random` is the principal module you need for actually doing randomness stuff. It's the public interface of  random-fu, as it were. `Data.RVar` is merely the _definition of the data type called `RVar`_, not a module that gives you routines for working with that.

Comment: In the discussion I mentioned that @leftaroundabout solved my issue. If he would go ahead and write up the answer I'll accept it. 1. It compiled because I used Unsafe and implicitly exported everything from Cover 5  2. I wasn't importing the public module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer(s) were provided by @leftaroundabout in the comments. Posting an answer here for others new to `Random` in case it proves helpful

**First Question**
I had written the original program about 3 years ago. I had no idea how to print results from `RVar`s. I chose to use `Data.Random.Show.Unsafe`. Apparently this module provides an instance of Show for `RVar a`. I didn't remember that.

In addition, I was implicitly exporting everything from my Cover5 module so the main module whose code is above was importing that instance.

So that's why `print` was working.

**Second Question**
Instances are available in `Data.Random`, which I wasn't importing.

The reason why I was getting errors but was thinking they were warnings is because I changed 2 (actually more than 2) things at once:

1. I restricted what was exported from Cover5 module so the Unsafe
   instance of Show wasn't exported anymore
2. I ran the build with some arguments which I thought were just going to show more warnings than a traditional build.